# Combat mechanism in Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands

Tags: prince-of-persia-forgotten-sands

I am playing Prince of Persia: The Forgotten Sands for the first time and I'm at the point where Malik unleashes the Solomon's Army.

From the past experience of playing The Warrior Within and The Two Thrones I can see a huge difference in the combat system. The game severly lacks "combos" or am I unaware of it?

In Two Thrones and in Warrior Within we could "Block with the sword, throw the secondary weapon, attack while wall running, do a swirl with the sword, throw the enemies" and much more.

I cannot see any of this in the Forgotten Sands, if there are any so called "combos" then a detailed description would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### Physical Abilities

#### Basic Moves

The basic combat abilities the Prince can perform include jump, dash, roll, slash, and push/kick.

#### Attack Chains

Press slash repeatedly to chain up to five slashes together. You can also mix in pushes/kicks.

#### Power Attack

Hold the attack button to perform a more powerful attack. This can be done standalone or at the end of an attack chain.

#### Aerial Attacks

Perform aerial attacks by jumping toward an enemy, then slashing or kicking in the air and/or when you land on them.

#### Finishing Lunge

Knock an enemy down, then attack while they're down to finish them off.

#### "Sparta" Kick

You can kill enemies by pushing or kicking them off a ledge.

### Powers of the Djinn

Shortly after Malik releases Ratash, the Prince meets a Djinn named Razia. Over repeated encounters, Razia grants the Prince powers to help him defeat Ratash. These powers can be upgraded by spending upgrade points, which are obtained by earning XP. Here are the ones that are useful in combat:

#### Ice Blast

The Prince's sword attacks release a blast of ice toward foes, dealing additional damage.

#### Rewind

The Prince rewinds up to a few seconds of time, allowing him to undo a mistake.

#### Stone Armor

The Prince is surrounded by stone, temporarily blocking all damage, although he can still be knocked down or staggered.

#### Trail of Flame

The Prince leaves a fire trail behind him as he moves. Enemies that get close to the Prince or step on the trail will ignite, incurring damage over a short time.

#### Whirlwind

The Prince slams his fist into the ground, releasing a blast of wind that knocks down nearby enemies. This gives him a momentary reprieve from their attacks, and creates opportunities to get in additional attacks while they're down.